# Form_for "First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty" error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I cannot figure out why I'm getting this error, and exactly what it means.

> First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty(Line 3)

#### Add a new Post

```
<%= form_for @post do |f| %>  //Error here
<p>
    <%= f.label :title, 'Title' %><br/>
    <%= f.text_field :title %><br/>
</p>
<p>
    <%= f.label :content, 'Content'%><br/>
    <%= f.text_area :content %><br/>
</p>
<p>
    <%= f.submit "Add a New Post" %>
</p>
<% end %>
```

Controller:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
    def index
        @posts = Post.all
    end

    def show
        @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    end

    def new
        @post = Post.new
    end

    def create
        @post = post.new(params[:post])

        if @post.save
            redirect_to posts_path,  :notice => "Your post was saved"
        else
            render "new"
        end
    end

    def edit

    end

    def update

    end

    def destroy

    end
end
```

Comment: how did you declare `@post`?

Comment: your @post should be nil

Comment: show us your controller code

Comment: my new action in post had a typo, thanks for your help

Comment: Surely `@post = post.new(params[:post])` should be `@post = Post.new(params[:post])

Comment: Voting to repoen, because I believe the question is pretty clear and unambiguous, and I'm fairly sure it's caused by the issue pointed out in the two answers below (disclaimer: one of the answers is mine).

Comment: Yours was correct, sorry it took so long to accept your answer, I thought I accepted long ago.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Assuming you are rendering this from `PostsController` and using the conventional view name, your `new` method should create a new `Post` and assign it:

```
def new
  @post = Post.new
end
```

You can use the class name (as @Yuriy suggested), but the conventional way is to instantiate a new object.  That allows you to re-use the same form view for rendering errors after a save.

If you want to see how this normally looks, create a new Rails project and use the scaffold generator to create some sample code.

Answer (score 1):

Use this (not recommended). It should work.

```
<%= form_for Post.new do |f| %>
```

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same error message.  I was just trying to get simpleform up and working and created a subdirectory within my view for testing forms when I got this error message and thought that simpleform wasn't installed.

I assumed that instance variables like `@user` were available to all my view files including those in lets say the `@clients` subdirectory and the `clients/_form` used for creating new clients.  My assumption was incorrect as `@user` will evaluate to `Nil` when used in say the `clients/_form` when it's created in the `@user` Controller.

Answer (score 0):

Your `@post` is `nil`

You should `form_for Post` instead for new post.

Comment: Can you please explain more on this? may be an example?

Comment: I second this comment. Where? In the controller? Or in the form?

Answer (score 0):

To understand this error there are two specific reasons why you get this error.

1. when you try to access the instance variable which is not defined or misspelled. For example in your controller if you define like

   ```
   def new
     @post = Post.new
    end
   ```

and you try to access in the view like

```
  <%= form_for @posts method: :post do |f| %> #plural name
```

in the above case you get the same error.

Another case is if you don't define the instance or  don't assign the instance variable in your controller and try to access it in the view you'll get the same error.