# First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am having an error where it says "First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty" in this form.

Form for asking a question, where the error says it is

```
<%= form_for(@question) do |f| %>
  <%= render 'common/form_errors', object: @question %>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :body, "Question" %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :body %>

    <%= f.submit "Ask a Question" %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

And this is my Questions Controller I'm not sure if whats in my controller is right

```
class QuestionsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :auth, only: [:create, :your_questions, :edit, :update]

  # def index
  #     @question = Question.new
  #   @questions = Question.unsolved(params)
  # end

  def self.unsolved(params)
    order('created_at DESC').where(solved: false).paginate(page: params[:page],per_page: 3)
  end

  def create
    @question = current_user.questions.build(params[:question])
    if @question.save
        flash[:success] = 'Your question has been posted!'
        redirect_to @question
    else
      @questions = Question.unsolved(params)
        render 'index'
    end
  end

  def show
    puts params
    @question = Question.find(params[:id])
    @answer = Answer.new
  end

  def your_questions
    @questions = current_user.your_questions(params[:id])
  end

  def edit
    @question = current_user.questions.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @question = current_user.questions.find(params[:id])

    if @question.update_attributes(params[:question])
      flash[:success] = 'Your question has been updated!'
      redirect_to @question
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

  def search
    @questions = Question.search(params)
  end
end
```

Comment: Basically, error says that `@question` is `nil` as @ruby_newbie said. To be able to help you more, please post at least which controller action is responsible for you form. Is it `edit` or `new`. Or you try to render form on the `index` action?

Answer (score 1):

If the form is for a 'new' page, add a new action for your Controller and initialize @question.

```
 class QuestionsController < ApplicationController 
    def new
       @question = Question.new
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is telling you that `@question` doesn't exist on the page of the form. The answer above is the correct one if the form is on the questions/new page. Whatever page you have the form on you need to define what `@question` is. So if the page is `foo.html.erb` you need to have the following in your questions controller:

```
def foo
  @question = question.new
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

Replace this:

```
<%= form_for(@question) do |f| %>
```

With

```
<%= form_for(@question||Question.new) do |f| %>
```

Comment: In place of this <%= form_for(@question) do |f| %>

Comment: yup replace only this: form_for(@question)

Answer (score 0):

I think your form is new.html.erb but there is no new action in your controller.

You should add new action in your controller to access the @question otherwise it would be nil

Add this in your controller.

```
def new
 @question = Question.new     #whatever
end
```

In the form add

```
    <%= form_for @question do |f| %>
      <%= render 'common/form_errors', object: @question %>
     <p>
      <%= f.label :body, "Question" %><br />
      <%= f.text_field :body %>
     <%= f.submit "Ask a Question" %>
   </p>
 <% end %>
```

If you want to understand this error more clearly please refer to my answer.
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27997082/3423992)