# Changing Rails form_for from symbol to object

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Right now my form_for works and looks like:

```
<%= form_for :post, url: posts_path do |f| %>
...
<% end %>
```

How can I change it to use a model, @post? A gem I'm using requires it.

The following does not work:

```
<%= form_for @post, url: posts_path do |f| %>
...
<% end %>
```

Comment: Remove the `url: posts_path` part.

Comment: @Iceman tried that, still doesn't work.

Comment: Doesn't work in what way, gives an error?

Comment: @Iceman yup an error, First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty

Comment: Well, then you haven't instantiated it in the controller.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Form\_for "First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty" error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15379495/form-for-first-argument-in-form-cannot-contain-nil-or-be-empty-error)

Comment: @Iceman how should I instantiate it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15379495/form-for-first-argument-in-form-cannot-contain-nil-or-be-empty-error

Comment: @Iceman, I added "@post = Post.new" in the "new" method of the controller. Now, the form shows up but nothing is created when i press submit.

Comment: What does your `create` action look like in PostsConrtroller?

Comment: @SteveTurczyn `def create
        @gif = Gif.new(gif_params)
        
        @gif.save
        redirect_to @gif
    end`

Comment: ? `@gif`?  So your example `@post` was just symbolic and we're really talking about Gif objects?

Comment: @SteveTurczyn They're post objects, sorry

Comment: Are your routes correct?

Comment: You don't need the **url** option as rails will determine that. Can you post the form elements also as I want to see how you have defined them?