# Subscriber email with ruby on rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-models

I'm trying to create a subscription via email, subscribers should receive an automatic email whenever I create a new article in the blog and when they subscribe. I always get this error "First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty" when I try this feature. Any suggestions?

This is the schema:

```
create_table "articles", force: :cascade do |t|
t.string   "title"
t.text     "body"
t.string   "image_url"
t.string   "video_url"
t.datetime "created_at", null: false
t.datetime "updated_at", null: false


end

  create_table "subscribers", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "email"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end
```

this is the model:

```
class Subscriber < ApplicationRecord
  after_create :send_mail
  def send_mail
    SubscriptionMailer.welcome_message(self).deliver
  end
end
```

This is the mailer:

```
class SubscriptionMailer < ApplicationMailer
  def send_email(email,article)
    @article = article
    mail(to: email,
    subject: 'XXXXXXX')
  end
end
```

This is the controller:

```
class SubscribersController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @subscriber = Subscriber.new
  end

  def create
    @subscriber = Subscriber.new(params[:subscriber])
    @subscriber.save
    redirect_to root_path
  end

end
```

Comment: SubscriptionMailer.welcome_message(self).deliver here where is welcome_message method defined in  SubscriptionMailer ?

Comment: and In Subscriber model you are passing one argument ie  SubscriptionMailer.welcome_message(self) and in mailer you are passing two arguments.

Comment: I think inside send_mail method, self is the whole subscriber when in fact you need the email. Also you're passing one argument instead of two and the name of the method is different. I would rather pass the id of the record and fetch it inside the mailer instead of whole objects.

Comment: Please paste the stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Subscriber < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :article

  after_create :send_mail

  def send_mail
    SubscriptionMailer.welcome_message(self).deliver
  end
end
```

In mailer

```
class SubscriptionMailer < ApplicationMailer
  def welcome_message(subscriber)
    @article = Article.joins(:subscribers).where("subscribers.id= ?", self.id)
    @email = subscriber.email
    mail(to: @email,
    subject: 'XXXXXXX')
  end
end
```

In Articles model

```
  class Article < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :subscribers
  end
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, I tried your solution but it doesn't work, I always get the same error.

Comment: Can u please paste article controller and form.

Comment: I think the error is in the subscriber form:

<% form_for(@subscriber) do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :email %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>

Comment: try this <%= form_for(Subscriber.new) do |f| %>

Comment: ref this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18853721/first-argument-in-form-cannot-contain-nil-or-be-empty-rails-4,

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15379495/form-for-first-argument-in-form-cannot-contain-nil-or-be-empty-error